# Output of Gradle Node task differs in encoding from running same command in Node

Tags: node.js, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle to execute `lint-staged` and `npm-groovy-lint` via the Gradle Node plugin, on a Windows system. The output of running these commands differs from the output generated when running the tools directly in Node.

**Node output**

```
npm-groovy-lint results in  linted files:
┌─────────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ (index) │ Severity  │ Total found │ Total fixed │ Total remaining │
├─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┤
│    0    │  'Error'  │      0      │      0      │        0        │
│    1    │ 'Warning' │      1      │      0      │        1        │
│    2    │  'Info'   │     46      │     11      │       35        │
└─────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

**Gradle output**

```
npm-groovy-lint results in  linted files:
ΓöîΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö¼ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö¼ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö¼ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö¼ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö?
Γöé (index) Γöé Severity  Γöé Total found Γöé Total fixed Γöé Total remaining Γöé
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö╝ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö╝ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö╝ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö╝ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöñ
Γöé    0    Γöé  'Error'  Γöé      0      Γöé      0      Γöé        0        Γöé
Γöé    1    Γöé 'Warning' Γöé      1      Γöé      0      Γöé        1        Γöé
Γöé    2    Γöé  'Info'   Γöé     46      Γöé     11      Γöé       35        Γöé
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö┤ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö┤ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö┤ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓö┤ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÿ
```

Explicitly setting the Gradle encoding (`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`) modifies the output slightly, but still does not match the Node output.

I would prefer to use Gradle for this, but if necessary I can use a Node script instead.

**UPDATE**

This is reproducible with a simple Gradle task to print one of the table characters using Node:

```
task nodeLog {
    exec {
        commandLine 'node', '-e', "console.log('┌')"
    }
}
Output: Γöî
```

**Versions**
Gradle wrapper: 7.2
Java: 11.0.12_7
Gradle Node plugin: 5.0.0
Node: 16.20.1
lint-staged: 13.2.3
npm-groovy-lint: 11.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the default encoding of the Windows console, which is DOS Latin US (code page 437). Switching the code page to UTF-8 (`chcp 65001`) allows the console to properly display the UTF-8 characters produced by Node.

Information on this issue and how to resolve it was found here: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_1252

In searching for ways to permanently set the default code page for Windows, I found numerous warnings **NOT TO DO THIS**, as it can break several Windows functions.